# TeXmaker citation

Tags: texmaker, mac, auto-completion

I'm using a Mac and I have a problem with my TeXmaker. Everything works great with TeXmaker but I'm having problems with citations. My TeXmaker is linked with Mendeley software and I can see all of my citation keys in TeXmaker but whenever I want to cite something, my citation list doesn't show anything.

Take for example, in my friend's PC whenever they want to cite, they write the first letter of citation key, TeXmaker brings the whole name, but in my Mac it doesn't work.

I've updated all of my packages. Please help me.

Comment: Just to clarify my confused mind: is the problem that autocompletion of citation keys in Texmaker doesn't work, or that the reference list doesn't appear in the PDF?

Comment: yes the problem is from autocompletion of citation key in Textmaker, i dont know why it doesnt work

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be of much help. Do you have the latest version of Texmaker? Have you added either `\bibliography{nameofbibfile}` to your document or `\addbibresource{nameofbibfile.bib}` to the preamble? (Packages are irrelevant here, this seems to be purely a Texmaker-problem.)

Comment: thanks bro, but i dont now what happend for my Tecmaker, it's last version, i update all packages but still... can u clarify me what do u mean by bibliography to my document?

Comment: In your `.tex` file, do you have a line such as `\bibliography{<name of .bib file>}` or `\addbibresource{<name of .bib file>.bib}`? If so, try Edit --> Refresh Bibliography.

Comment: Try the autocomplete with this simple example. The .tex file is here [http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex] and .bib file from [http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib]. You might need to press **Refresh Bibliography** button at the bottom the Edit Menu in Texmaker 3.5 to get the autocomplete of citation keys sometimes if the .bib file is large in size