# Auto citation in TeXmaker

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, texmaker

My problem is similar to 
[TeXmaker citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69274/texmaker-citation)

But as the above thread is closed so I am putting it as new question.

In my TeXmaker, the auto-completion works fine except for the citations which are to be pulled from `mybibfile.bib`. I have `\bibliography{mybibfile}` in my `.tex` file and I have no issue in generating list of references. My problem is, in TeXmaker, the auto completion for citations is not working. My bib file is in `~\texmf\bibtex\bib` directory and so I do not need to provide the path for the bib file in the `.tex` document.

Version: Texmaker 4.0.1 - 10 Year Anniversary Edition
(compiled with Qt 4.8.1)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

I am compiling the `.tex` document using `pdflatex` and `bibtex`.

**EDIT: when I put the .bib file in the working folder, everything works perfectly. How can I work with autocompletion for citation keeping the .bib file in `~\texmf\bibtex\bib` folder ?**

Comment: Normally TeXmaker detects `.bib` files inside `main.tex` folder for auto completion of bib keys, i doubt TeXmaker can detect files in other directories because it does not have `Kpathsea` type path searching.

Comment: @texenthusiast That's as close as we're likely to get to an answer: could you make it one?

Answer (score 3):

Normally TeXmaker detects `.bib` files inside `main.tex` folder for auto completion of `bib keys`, I doubt TeXmaker can detect files in `other directories` because it does not have `Kpathsea` type path searching.

Hence include `.bib` files in the same folder as `main.tex` for better auto-completion of `bib keys` in TeXmaker.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. If I added a source to my `.bib` file, it would not show up in auto-complete.

I fixed the problem by closing the `.bib` file and then reopening it in TeXmaker. After doing that, the newly added sources showed up in auto-complete.

Comment: Sometimes I need to press `Edit` -> `Refresh Bibliography` to refresh the bibliography list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have sometimes issues of the same kind, with a biblio.bib file, loaded by a biblio.tex file, placed in subfolder of the working directory.

It seems that **the different concerned files have to be all opened in TexMaker (and optionnally reloaded)**, i.e. the main.tex, biblio.tex and biblio.bib.

It also seems that a little delay is required to load the different bibliography keys, depending on their amount...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.